# How to selective test go modules with go test?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I'm working in a large legacy codebase with lots of broken tests making running `go test ./...` returning a lot of failed tests that I don't want to focus on right now.

I tried using `+build` which is good enough for targeting certain sub-package but it runs all of the test not configured as well. Going through all the tests right now is not an option for me.

Currently I have to do it the long way with:

```
go test \
-coverprofile=coverage.out \
-tags=moduleB_feature1,moduleA_feature1,moduleA_feature3 \
code_dir/projectX/moduleA/... \
code_dir/projectY/moduleB/feature1
```

Is there a command for me to ignore all the test without `+build` configured so I can use `./...`?

Answer (score 2):

You can run test for specific sub-package. E.g., if you have package `example.org/your/module/some/package` then the command

```
go test example.org/your/module/some/package
```

executes tests for `some/package` only.

It could be combined with selecting tests by regular expression: [`-run`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags) switch

```
go test example.org/your/module/some/package -run `Foo`
```

executes all test functions from the package `some/package` that match the regular expression `Foo`, such as `TestFooBar(t *testing.T)`

Comment: Would this not cause the test report/coverage to split into multiple runs as well?

Comment: @RobGThai Each test run provides a separate coverage report. There are utilities to merge them, e.g. https://github.com/wadey/gocovmerge